# What is container in container managed entity manager?

Tags: jpa

What is container in the **container managed entity manager?**
Does this term refer to the servlet containers such as Tomcat or Weblogic or Glassfish?

I have read so many articles about its functioning. But none describes what "container" means.

Please explaint this specific term.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between Container Managed and Application Managed EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489057/differences-between-container-managed-and-application-managed-entitymanager)

Answer (score 0):

Container refers to the PersistenceContext.

The PersistenceContext is a container that has the ability to cache entities that can be synchronized with a database by using EntityManager.

Depending on the PersistenceContext type that is specified when its EntityManager is created, a PersistenceContext can either be defined to have a life that is limited to a single transaction or an extended lifetime that spans multiple transactions.

In container-managed (limited to a single transaction), When a method on a bean is called, a transaction will automatically be started and a new PersistenceContext will be created for you.
When the method ends at the end of the transaction and the persistence context will be closed, your entities will become detached.

Application-managed, means that the current PersistenceContext lives as long as your bean lives. in fact, the PersistenceContext can share across multiple transactions.